# Android: Native crash with BitmapShader_constructor

Tags: android

I got the below crash report at PlayStore with a title **in abort**. How do I even come to reproduce it or make any sense of it?

```
  #00  pc 000000000001a528  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+63)
  #01  pc 0000000000006641  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+156)
  #02  pc 00000000000cb83f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::bitmap::toBitmap(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+34)
  #03  pc 00000000000dcb23  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (BitmapShader_constructor(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, _jobject*, int, int)+38)
  #04  pc 0000000000a31c23  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.BitmapShader.nativeCreate [DEDUPED]+146)
  #05  pc 0000000000a31d53  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.BitmapShader.createNativeInstance+66)
  #06  pc 0000000000a31793  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Shader.getNativeInstance+98)
  #07  pc 0000000000a4cb27  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Paint.getNativeInstance+70)
  #08  pc 000000000110554f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawRoundRect+78)
  #09  pc 000000000004699f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_12384_12384 (deleted)
```

The crash only happens in **Android 8.1**, here is the list the devices on which it happened, do you think those are real?

```
Device Name                 Count 
*************************************
Redmi 6 (cereus)            5   35.7%
Redmi 6A (cactus)           2   14.3%
GM8 Go (GM8_go_sc)          1   7.1%
Galaxy J7 (j7y17lte)        1   7.1%
Nokia 1 (FRT)               1   7.1%
ZTE BLADE A530 (P639F10)    1   7.1%
Redmi S2 (ysl)              1   7.1%
Smart 2 HD (Infinix-X609B)  1   7.1%
Galaxy J7 Neo (j7velte)     1   7.1%
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue on my Redmi 6A, with no success. I was using a custom view drawing with a bitmap shader. The android (under the hood) used native bitmap shader, native paint and recording canvas. Everything was OK. I could try to install your app from the Google play if you want.

Comment: Yes please, if you be able to reproduce it, it will be awesome

Comment: Ilya, what app is it? I don't see any references in the description.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Here is the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gazman.beep&hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce this on my xiaomi/cactus_ru/cactus:8.1.0/O11019/V9.6.14.0.OCBRUFD.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Open main activity
- Click 'add user' button
- Type valid name and phone number
- Click done

This results in a crash with the following logs (Reproduces in 100% of cases):

```
7.103 31159 31159 W Bitmap  : Called getWidth() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
01-25 13:52:07.103 31159 31159 W Bitmap  : Called getHeight() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
01-25 13:52:07.103 31159 31159 F Bitmap  : Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!
--------- beginning of crash
01-25 13:52:07.104 31159 31159 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 31159 (com.gazman.beep), pid 31159 (com.gazman.beep)
01-25 13:52:07.129 29843 29952 D SyncAccountUtils: getSelectionWritableAccountTypes(): readonly types: ('com.google.android.apps.tachyon','com.google.android.gms.matchstick','com.whatsapp')
01-25 13:52:07.198 31306 31306 I crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
01-25 13:52:07.199   541   541 I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 31159
01-25 13:52:07.200 31306 31306 I crash_dump32: performing dump of process 31159 (target tid = 31159)
01-25 13:52:07.201 31159 31159 I libc    : orig_dumpable: 0
01-25 13:52:07.201 31306 31306 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-25 13:52:07.201 31306 31306 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/cactus_ru/cactus:8.1.0/O11019/V9.6.14.0.OCBRUFD:user/release-keys'
01-25 13:52:07.201 31306 31306 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
01-25 13:52:07.202 31306 31306 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
01-25 13:52:07.202 31306 31306 F DEBUG   : pid: 31159, tid: 31159, name: com.gazman.beep  >>> com.gazman.beep <<<
01-25 13:52:07.202 31306 31306 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-25 13:52:07.202 31306 31306 F DEBUG   : Abort message: ''
01-25 13:52:07.203 31306 31306 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 000079b7  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
01-25 13:52:07.203 31306 31306 F DEBUG   :     r4 000079b7  r5 000079b7  r6 bec6e474  r7 0000010c
01-25 13:52:07.203 31306 31306 F DEBUG   :     r8 00000000  r9 00000000  sl 12f0f670  fp 12f0f538
01-25 13:52:07.203 31306 31306 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000000  sp bec6e460  lr a6efb8bd  pc a6ef540e  cpsr 200f0030
01-25 13:52:07.204 31306 31306 F DEBUG   : 
01-25 13:52:07.204 31306 31306 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
01-25 13:52:07.205 31306 31306 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0001a40e  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+63)
01-25 13:52:07.205 31306 31306 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000208bb  /system/lib/libc.so (sigprocmask+46)
01-25 13:52:07.392 31306 31306 I crash_dump: socket name: android:aee_aed, sfd: 9
```